# PostgreSQL multidimensional arrays in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy 0.6.3 with PostgreSQL 8.4 on Debian squeeze. I want a table where one column stores something in PostgreSQL that shows up in Python as a list of integer lists or tuples of integer tuples. E.g.

```
((1,2), (3,4), (5,6,7))
```

In the example below that column is `model`. I thought that a reasonable approach might be to store stuff as an PG 2 dimensional table, which in PG looks like `integer[][]`. I don't know in what form SQLA will return this to Python, but I'm hoping it is something like a tuple of tuples.

However, I can't figure out how to tell SQLA to give me a two dimensional Integer array. The [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_6/dialects/postgresql.html#postgresql-data-types) for `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY` says

> item_type – The data type of items of this array. Note that
>   dimensionality is irrelevant here, so multi-dimensional arrays like
>   INTEGER[][], are constructed as ARRAY(Integer), not as
>   ARRAY(ARRAY(Integer)) or such. The type mapping figures out on the fly.

Unfortunately, I have no idea what that means. How can the type mapping figure this out on the fly? It needs to create the correct DDL.
My first and only guess for how to do this would have been `ARRAY(ARRAY(Integer))`. Currently I have

```
  crossval_table = Table(
        name, meta,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('created', TIMESTAMP(), default=now()),
        Column('sample', postgresql.ARRAY(Integer)),
        Column('model', postgresql.ARRAY(Integer)),
        Column('time', Float),
        schema = schema,
```

This creates the following DDL

```
CREATE TABLE crossval (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    created timestamp without time zone,
    sample integer[],
    model integer[],
    "time" double precision
);
```

which isn't right, of course. What am I missing?

Comment: If your going to do a lot of this kind of thing then you may wont to consider weather a relational db is the best option for you.

Comment: @Mark: I don't follow. A lot of what kind of thing?

Comment: If you are trying to persist lots of arrays of arrays or maps of maps etc then you may wont to look at a database which supports that concept as a 1st class eg redis

Comment: @Mark: Ok, I see. No, it just a convenient placeholder for some information. Nothing very important.

Comment: If most of the rest of your data is nice and relation then I gess it makes seance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm answering this here, since Mike Bayer responded to this question on sqlalchemy users.

See the [thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.sqlalchemy.user/31186) on sqlalchemy-user where Mike Bayer responds to this question. As Mike clarified, and as I missed when reading the PG documentation, PG does not actually enforce the array dimensions, nor does SQLA. So, one can write `integer[][]`, but PG does not treat that any differently from `integer[]`. In particular, both PG and SQLA will accept an array expression of any dimension. I'm not sure why this is the case. As quoted by Mike, the [PG Arrays documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) says

> The current implementation does not enforce the declared number of
>   dimensions either. Arrays of a particular element type are all
>   considered to be of the same type, regardless of size or number of
>   dimensions. So, declaring the array size or number of dimensions in
>   CREATE TABLE is simply documentation; it does not affect run-time
>   behavior.

See also the [ticket](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/2441) he opened.
It looks like this is to enforce dimensions at the SQLA level.

Answer (score 4):

I tried this

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('postgresql://:5432/test', echo=True)

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

Base = declarative_base()


from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    sample = Column(postgresql.ARRAY(Integer))


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(engine)
s = Session()

a = User()
a.name='test'
a.sample = [[1,2], [3,4]]
s.add(a)
s.commit()
```

I think this will solve your problem. Because in [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION) they mention.

> However, the current implementation ignores any supplied array size limits, i.e., the behavior is the same as for arrays of unspecified length.

So if you are not declare anything then it will be the array which you want.

Comment: Hi Lafada. You were in the right ballpark, but quoted the wrong piece of documentation. The issue was about dimensions, not array size limits. See my update above. Since you are the only person to reply, if you fix your answer, I'll accept it. :-)

Comment: You need to declare `integer[][]` instead of `integer[]` by sqlalchemy. But now its out of my knowledge for sqlalchemy :).

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow this comment.